# How to use association in field_for with simple-form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have three model: User, Fruit, Tag

User has many Fruits, Fruit belongs to user: one-to-many

Fruit has many Tags, Tag has many Fruits: many-to-many

When I create a new User, I create a new fruit and select a tag.

But I occur an error `Association :tags not found`

My current code is:

```
= simple_form_for(@user) do |f|
  = f.error_notification

      .form-inputs
        = f.input :name
        = f.simple_fields_for :fruits do |fl|
          = fl.error_notification
          .form-inputs
            = fl.input :name
            = fl.association :tags
      .form-actions
        = f.button :submit
```

user.rb

```
class User
  has_many :fruits
end
```

fruit.rb

```
class Fruit
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tagging, as: :taggable
  has_many :tags, through: :tagging
end
```

tag.rb

```
class Tag
  has_many :taggings
end
```

tagging.rb

```
class Tagging
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`simple_fields_for` works in the same way that the [fields_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) Rails helper.

As, your `Fruit` has many `Tags`, so you should use:

```
= fl.simple_fields_for :tags
```

instead of:

```
= fl.association :tags
```

So, your code should look like this:

```
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :name
    = f.simple_fields_for :fruits do |fl|
      = fl.error_notification
      .form-inputs
        = fl.input :name
        = fl.simple_fields_for :tags
  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit
```

#### Update

If you want to select a tag from a list of tags rather than creating a new tag, you can do something like this:

```
= fl.input :tags, as: :check_boxes, checked: Tag.pluck(&:id)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it still has error `private method 'binding' called for nil:NilClass`, and I only want to select the tags not create a new tag.

Comment: Oh ok. If you want to select a tag, you should something like this: `= fl.input :tags, as: :check_boxes, checked: Tag.pluck(&:id)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
= fl.collection_select :tag_ids, Tag.all, :id, :name
```

Put that in place of `= fl.association :tags`.

--

Ref [`collection_singular_ids`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many)